# Lightning component using lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-datatable

I rebuilt my lightning components using lightning:datatable feature in Salesforce pages and worked perfectly. But it doesn't work on Community pages.

COMPONENT

```
<aura:component controller="Ass_ScopeAuraController" access="global" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
  <aura:attribute name="scoperows" type="Scope__c[]" /> 

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="id" />  
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String" default="asc"/>

    <p>
            <b> Scope by Unit Standard</b>
        </p>

    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.scoperows}" 
                         columns="{!v.mycolumns}" 
                         keyField="Id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                         sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                         onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting }"
                         sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"/>   
  </aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'US', fieldName: 'Standard_Code__c', type: 'number', sortable: true},
            {label: 'Standard Name', fieldName: 'Standard_Name__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},
            {label: 'Scope Added', fieldName: 'Scope_Added_Date__c', type: 'date', sortable: true},
            {label: 'Assessment Count', fieldName: 'Assessment_Count__c', type: 'number', sortable: true}
        ]);

        var action = component.get("c.getScope");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            component.set("v.scoperows", response.getReturnValue()); 
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
 updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
    cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
    helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
  }
})
```

HELPER

```
({
    sortData: function (cmp, fieldName, sortDirection) {
        var data = cmp.get("v.scoperows");
        var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
        //sorts the rows based on the column header that's clicked
        data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
        cmp.set("v.scoperows", data);
    },

    sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
        var key = primer ? function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : function(x) {return x[field]};
        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
        return function (a, b) {
            return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error, no response at all.